# Controller spec fails with a 501 Not Implemented status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to add tests to an old app I started working on, but I'm failing miserably :(

It's a Rails 2.3.8 app with Rspec 1.3.2 and Rspec-rails 1.3.4.

This is all I have right now on a controller spec:

```
before(:each) do
  @attributes = { ... }
end

it 'should create a notification' do
  post 'create', :notification => @attributes
  assigns[:notification].should_not be_new_record
end
```

I spent hours trying to figure out why the `@notification` variable wasn't being set, and I just found out the response has been `501 Not Implemented` all this time...

Of course the controller works fine from a browser, so for the life of me I can't figure out why I'm getting that error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Bah, I forgot to clone the test database so some of the attributes I was assigning weren't on the test DB, and thus the error.

I only found out after I remembered `log/test.log` exists... I'm glad nobody answered first or I'd be even more embarrased :D

Comment: Please don't be embarrassed by not knowing things. You are human and you cannot be expected to know everything immediately. Great to see you could solve this before someone else could come along and answer your question though!